# Reverse MoveMouseRelative Lua Codding

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)

  OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
  if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
  elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
    ReleaseMouseButton(2) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
  elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" 
               and (arg == 5 or arg == 4) then 
    recoil = recoil ~= arg and arg
  elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" 
               and arg == 1 and recoil == 5 then
    MoveMouseRelative(0, -3) 
    for i = 1, 17 do
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)  
      Sleep(15)
      if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then return end

    end

  elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" 
               and arg == 1 and recoil == 4 then
    MoveMouseRelative(0, -3) 
    for i = 1, 35 do
      Sleep(15)
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)       
      if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then return end
    end
    if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then return end
  end
end
```

This is the Lua Script , I wonder how i can get mouse initial position and after it to return to the initial position.

I tried to add MoveMousePosition(x,y)- (32767, 32767 ) at bottom of script but not worked in game . Only on desktop ..

I just want after MoveMouseRelative when i release mouse click to return center or first position .

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff - please help me , i know ur expert in these lua issues.

Comment: I'm still dizzy from you formatting, but I think the main problem here is that you can't set absolute positions while in relative mode (e.g. games). Is this the case? If yes, just use `MoveMouseRelative` and undo your movement. So for your first script `MoveMouseRelative(0, 3 - 17 * 2)`

Comment: i tried this before but if i just use tap fire - like press for 2 seconds it will go up faster than the moment i want from  undo-ed position . and if i want to keep pressing longer than  i can't becasue MoveMouseRelative(0, 3 - 17 * 2) will start after 'for statement' is over. I need in this script to introduce when click is on record position and when click is released to return that position , in both scripts i want to add that. Thanks anyway for Undo information , i will think in future to make one with undo statement

Comment: I think I understand. Keep track of the total moved position. E.g. after calling `MoveMouseRelative` increase `MouseMovedY` or something as well (maybe introduce a function doing both). Then, whenever you want to reset, use the stored value and reset it to 0 (basically your `undo()`).

Comment: I understand what you said but can you do an example for me ? I m begginer with this , i need some Variable to get +1 when mouse is moved on Y axe and when  not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) to return First position ?

Comment: Hopefully, my answer helps. I can't post the full code, but it should be enough to put together what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Luke100000 said, you need an "undo" movement (the same distance with the opposite sign).

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and (arg == 5 or arg == 4) then
      recoil = recoil ~= arg and arg
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil == 5 then
      MoveMouseRelative(0, -3)
      local n = 0
      for i = 1, 17 do
         n = n + 1
         MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)
         Sleep(15)
         if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
      end
      repeat  -- wait for LMB release
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      for i = 1, n do
         MoveMouseRelative(0, -2)
      end
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 3)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil == 4 then
      MoveMouseRelative(0, -3)
      local n = 0
      for i = 1, 35 do
         Sleep(15)
         n = n + 1
         MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)
         if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
      end
      repeat  -- wait for LMB release
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      for i = 1, n do
         MoveMouseRelative(0, -2)
      end
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 3)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To undo any operations we need a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)), where you remember everything you did. But since we only have a single position and therefore the order does not matter, we use a simple number to store the total moved x and y instead.

```lua
local movedX = 0
local movedY = 0
function move(x, y)
    MoveMouseRelative(x, y)
    movedX = movedX + x
    movedY = movedY + y
end
```

Now you use e.g. `move(0, 2)` only.

To undo we do the opposite; since we only have a number by subtracting it.

```lua
function undo()
    MoveMouseRelative(-movedX, -movedY)
    movedX = 0
    movedY = 0
end
```

Unrelated, but in your loop, do not use `return` but `break`. That way you can reach the end of the event and add an `undo()` there.

Comment: I understood what i should do , but like i said is hard for me to implement this in that script . Even with first script i had much help. I don t know how to induct this in my script

Comment: I hope I don't sound too rude, but I want you to learn the basics of programming. Stackoverflow can't just code stuff for you, only help :)